# unparseable unix timestamp

Tags: java, date

Unix timestamp is 1334672401.

```
long t = Long.parseLong(map.get("timestamp").toString());   
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, ''yy, hh:mma");
Date time = new Date(t*1000);
Date date = formatter.parse(time.toString());
```

I'm trying to convert a unix timestamp into a Date object in the format to something similar to Thu Apr 17 2012, 16:25 but I keep getting an unparseable date error and I'm not sure whats wrong exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the Date object already when you did this:

```
Date time = new Date(t*1000);
```

Use the formatter to format your string output, like this:

```
System.out.println(formatter.format(time));
```